# how to fit an different images to the div box with a fixed size

Tags: html, css

there are different images that i want to display inside a div box, whatever the image size, Div box size should be the same.

I couldn't fit the image, when the image is larger, it goes out of the div box. that affects the Ui of my website that I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

img {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.d2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>source image larger than div so it overflows</p>
<div class="d1">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/146/180/120">
</div>

<p>source image is scaled until its shorter dimension fits the div, then the other dimension is cropped</p>
<div class="d2">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/146/180/120">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code as an example and you need to make changes accordingly in your code.
Here I am having a main div as image-container. I am applying CSS to div and image inside the div.

```
   <div class="image-container">
      <img src="path_to_your_image.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>


    .image-container {
      width: 300px; /* Set your desired width */
      height: 200px; /* Set your desired height */
      overflow: hidden; /* Ensure that the image doesn't overflow the container */
      background-color: #ccc; /* Optional: set a background color for the container */
    }
    
    .image-container img {
      width: 100%; /* Ensure the image fills the container horizontally */
      height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
      display: block; /* Remove any potential whitespace below the image */
    }
```

Hope it helps and see how it goes.